# Checkboxes in exposed form in block aren't checked in initial state

Tags: views, forms

I have views with exposed form.

In filter criteria I have filter category which has 4 checkboxes.

If I choose to display exposed form in block, in initial state checkboxes aren't checked but results appears for each of them. It seems like a bug, user is not selected nothing but results are there. I want to these checkboxes be checked in initial state when the page is opened.

If exposed form isn't displayed in block, the checkboxes are checked in initial state.

I also try to change with form alter but without success, I couldn't print anything

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'views_exposed_form':
            krumo($form);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so you might have to checkboxes when you expose the form and save the view.